# Update the form on select change Struts2

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery

I have select tag outside the form , in onchange event of select i publish the listenTopics of anchor tag and get the result in json which is correct but it 
replaces the form with json data I need to update the form. Any idea what might be wrong here or there is any other way to do this.

```xml
<script type="text/javascript">
    function reloadForm() {
        $.publish('reloadFormList');
    }
</script>

<div id="body" style="text-align: center;width: 100%;">
    <s:form id="formSelect" style="margin-top:20px;">
        <s:select list="model.classList" name="model.selectedID" 
                  listKey="classID" listValue="className" headerKey="-1" 
                  headerValue="" theme="simple" label="Class" 
                  style="margin-bottom:10px;" onchange="reloadForm();" />
        <sj:a formIds="formSelect" href="getEmailSett" targets="form"
              style="display:none;" listenTopics="reloadFormList"></sj:a>
    </s:form>

    <s:form id="form">
        <s:checkbox label="OPtion1" title="OPtion1" name="model.chk_option1"
                    style="margin-top:20px;"></s:checkbox>
        <s:checkbox label="OPtion2" title="OPtion2" name="model.chk_option2" 
                    style="margin-top:20px;"></s:checkbox>
        <sj:submit id="formSubmit" href="mysubmit" value="Update"
                   indicator="indicator" button="true" />
    </s:form>
</div>
```

Comment: You returning json and want to update html.

Comment: create a callback function that will handle json returned by the action then update a target.

Comment: edit your question and show **what json data are you getting**? 
And what output you want

Comment: @RomanC there is no direct way

Comment: @RomanC the request isreturning <form id="form" name="form" action="/struts2Example/email.action" method="post">{"model":{"chk_option1":false,"chk_option2":false}}</form> in onSuccessTopics of anchor tag

Comment: @Haider You cannot use json as a target of your link, you need to parse json and modify target html.

Comment: @RomanC any method that is called before the target is populated because onSuccessTopics is called after target is populated, beacuse when i debug in chrome by debugger is in that function and target is populated with json data?

Comment: @RomanC here what i can do i create a dummy target with display none, and on onSuccessTopics  get json obj with JSON.parse($(data).html())  and then populate the form. Please tell me if you have some better idea how to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tell you what are you doing wrong because a lot of questions posted with the same topic. A common mistake is to use `targets` for json results. `targets` should be used to load html/javascript content. If you want to handle json result, then you shouldn't write such ugly code

```
<sj:a formIds="formSelect" href="getEmailSett" targets="form"
          style="display:none;" listenTopics="reloadFormList"></sj:a>
```

In the `reloadForm()` you should write a normal ajax call via `$.ajax()` or `$.getJSON()` and in the callback success function used to modify your DOM.

If you still continue to use `targets` then you should change result of the triggered action to `dispatcher` to return  html/javascript content.